# Not getting expected parameter on a function from an eventlistner callback

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

I am using a **functional react component** in which I am trying to **add events** to a **couple of elements** altogether. However I am not able to pass a `trigger` element to a function

```js
export default function Header() {
    const background = document.querySelector('.dropdownBackground');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.top');

    useEffect(() => {
        let triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.cool > li');
        console.log(triggers);
        triggers.forEach(trigger => {
            trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', trigger => handleEnter(trigger));
        });
    });

    function handleEnter(trigger) {
        // not getting proper value or trigger here. 
        // I am getting a MouseEvent object instead of a HTML element
        trigger.classList.add('trigger-active');
    }

    return (
        <nav className='header top w-100 justify-content-center'>
            <ul className='cool'>
                <li>
               {/* some HTML code */}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

ADDENDUM: Updated the code to provide all required details.

Thanks!!

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: Probably the elements don't exist at the time you are trying to add the event so the node list is 0 items long, but it is hard to tell because you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners with DOM methods instead of JSX props anyway? React is *designed* to work with JSX props.

Comment: try converting them to Array first `const triggers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cool>li'));`

Comment: Please provide the more code in your component. Direct DOM manipulation should be considered carefully.

Comment: Don't know if it's intended (beacuse we can't see the handlers' code) but you're passing the `MouseEvent` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) as an argument to your handler functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
triggers.forEach(trigger => {
    trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', trigger =>
handleEnter(trigger));
});
```

to:

```
triggers.forEach(trigger => {
    trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => // can also use () instead of 'event', as you are not using it
handleEnter(trigger));
});
```

If you use `(trigger)` as a parameter in your arrow functions, you are naming *trigger* the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), and passing it to the handlers

Comment: Thanks!! That seemed to have solved it.